# Phonegap: Is it possible to change orientation using javascript?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, orientation

I was wondering if within Phonegap it was possible to *disable* orientation changes using JavaScript alone. So not using an external plugin, or modifying the `config.xml` for example. I could not find any definitive answers to this question. The reason for this is we have an application that we package up and have customers download, which allows them to run their own mobile applications using a software product we offer. Since we want customers to have all the options available for their applications, this packaged application has both orientations enabled (this application was built using Phonegap obviously).

I was thinking perhaps there is an event I can listen for and disable its propagation. Another hack I was thinking of was if I could detect an orientation event, I can rotate the page in the opposite direction of the movement that triggered the orientation event, if its not possible to disable its propagation or stop the rotation in the first place.

Comment: no, it's not possible without a plugin